# Instead of transparency, the color is black

Tags: qt, qml

Can someone tell me why the window has a black background instead of transparency?

```
Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    opacity: 1
    visible: true
    color: "transparent"
 
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to notify a window manager that you want an transparent window , by default it is opaque. just add [Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#WidgetAttribute-enum).

```js
import QtQuick 2.14
import QtQuick.Window 2.14

Window {
    id: wnd
    width: 400
    height: 300
    visible: true
    color: "#80000000"
    //opacity: 0.5 // the same
    flags: Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground | Qt.FramelessWindowHint

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: wnd.close();
    }
}
```